# How to get nested JsonObject from Decoded JWT in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, jwt, auth0

I have already decode the token but i can't get the nested JsonObject. I want to get **id** in user_metadata:hasura.

```
{
  "exp": 16636813,
  "email": "123@gmail.com",
  "user_metadata": {
   "hasura": {
      "id": "123"
  }
}
```

I have used couple of Library, I have gotten `Option<String>` or `Claim`. But i couldn't go further than gettin only string value from **"exp"**.

I have tried this from this library (https://github.com/auth0/JWTDecode.Android), but i got null values:

```
var claim : Claim = jwt.getClaim("user_metadata")
metadata = claim.asObject(UserMetadata::class.java)!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that i was trying to claim my object as a **UserMetadata** class but actually it was **JsonObject**.

I have solved my question with this way:

```
var json : JsonObject = jwt.getClaim("user_metadata").asObject(JsonObject::class.java)!!
var gsonn = Gson()
var testModel = gsonn.fromJson(json.toString(),UserMetadata::class.java)
var id : String = testModel.hasura.id
```

Comment: I've been trying to find a good answer for this as well... I'd love to create data classes for the nested objects in the claims, but haven't found a good way to use them. I really want to avoid converting the object back to json to convert it back using a serializable class